# Ruby Date Formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If a user enters a search value in this format MM/DD/YYYY the following works:

`date = Date.strptime(search_value, "%m/%d/%Y")`

How can I accommodate if the user enters it like these:

MM-DD-YYYY - notice the dash instead of the slash
M-D-YYYY
M/D/YYYY

Currently, I am getting an invalid date if one of those are entered. I am trying to cover all of the different formats.

Answer (score 2):

```
date = Date.new(*search_value.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i).rotate(-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cover all your bases, and not reinvent the wheel, take a look at https://github.com/mojombo/chronic

Answer (score 0):

You can use gsub or gsub! method to replace dash to slash:
for example:

"04-01-2014".gsub("-","/")

this gives you result as below:

04/01/2014

i don`t know rest of the format you encountered, if you want help please 
show other formats also.